# Celery crontab misbehaves, spawns task every 5 minutes

Tags: django, cron, celery, django-celery, periodic-task

I am using Celery 3.1.25 (Cipator) `PeriodicTask` and it is set via the below code:

```
@periodic_task(name='download_foo', run_every=crontab(hour='*/2', minute=0))
```

Alos, I have set celery timezone settings as follows:

```
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

My task with `eta` are running good, but periodic tasks are spawning every 5 minutes.

PS: I have already `purged` the tasks in queue, deleted `celerybeat-schedule.db` file too.

Comment: did u try to restart your message broker (Redis or what do u have)? I had something similar with that, restart helped.

Comment: ok,  just let me try for once

Comment: @Chiefir it's still spawning at 5 minutes interval, i've restarted my broker